# JMeter & Mule load testing for file to file test

Tags: jmeter, mule

Is there a way to use JMeter to load test file to file inbound-outbound endpoints in mule?  New to JMeter.  Does JMeter have this capability or should I look to another framework to do file to file load testing?

Comment: Isn't enough to put a bit amount of files in a directory and let Mule consume all the files? You can then measure how many files, how many bytes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accomplished this kind of load test before using JUnit and the Mule FunctionalTestCase.  I simply create the files I need on my local filesystem under the target/ directory of the Mule application, and observe an output folder also under target/.

This allows me to understand the behavior of the mule application independent of other factors such as disk I/O contention on the server.

To the best of my knowledge, neither JMeter nor LoadUI offers a feature that would allow you to generate large numbers of files, nor to monitor for the output of files.

Comment: using FunctionalTestCase goes against the purpose of a load test, to run a load test you need to run Mule ESB Standalone in an environment as close to the production one as possible.

Comment: Yes, my only point was that I haven't yet found a good way to automate an integrated load test, and that you can still learn something about your Mule application's behavior with an isolated test.  Your comment on the original question is how I actually do test these kinds of flows currently.